# Transpose Query in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, transpose

I've the following table:

```
tb_item
id_item | item_name | price
----------------------------
1       | item1     | 2000
2       | item2     | 3000
3       | item3     | 4000
```

and

```
tb_value
id_value | id_item | value_type | value
----------------------------------------
1        | 1       | bedroom    | 2
2        | 1       | bathroom   | 1
3        | 2       | bedroom    | 3
4        | 2       | bathroom   | 1
5        | 3       | bedroom    | 4
6        | 3       | bathroom   | 2
```

I would like to get an output like this:

```
item_name | price | bedroom | bathroom
---------------------------------------
item1     | 2000  | 2       | 1
item2     | 3000  | 3       | 1
item3     | 4000  | 4       | 2
```

I'm using PostgreSQL; what query can be used to get this output?
I'm using PHP too; is there a PHP function that can do this?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , Am I able to directly use these functions? or need an installation before?

Comment: @FrankBollack, no, it's a part of my job,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also accomplish this with a couple `LEFT JOIN` statements

```
SELECT i.item_name
   , i.price
   , bed.value AS bedroom
   , bath.value AS bathroom
FROM tb_item AS i
LEFT JOIN tb_value AS bed ON i.id_item = bed.id_item
   AND bed.value_type = 'bedroom'
LEFT JOIN tb_value AS bath ON i.id_item = bath.id_item
   AND bath.value_type = 'bathroom'
```

Comment: +1 for separating the `JOIN` conditions from the `WHERE` filter condition.

Comment: @A.H. Yes there was, sorry. I've updated it, Thank you for catching that.

Comment: thanks a lot, I wanna vote up your answer, but I can't do it yet, :D

Answer (score 0):

```
select item_name, price, bedroom.value as bedroom, bathroom.value as bathroom
from tb_item, tb_value as bedroom, tb_value as bathroom
where bedroom.id_item=tb_item.id_item and bedroom.value_type='bedroom'
and bathroom.id_item=tb_item.id_item and bathroom.value_type='bathroom'
```